# How can I filter json based on the timestamp? UNIX

Tags: json, unix, awk

I am interacting with an API that returns me jsons such as these (with more attributes in fact):

```
 {"timestamp": {"$date": 1488192218325}, "_id":103482}
 {"timestamp": {"$date": 1488192216265}, "_id":302719}
 {"timestamp": {"$date": 1588192216260}, "_id":302719}
```

and I want to filter these json based on the timestamp. I only want the json between 2 dates (1488192216263 and 1488192216269). My expected output is:

```
 {"timestamp": {"$date": 1488192216265}, "_id":302719}
```

How can I do it? Can I use grep or awk?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: @JamesJithin I have tried awk '$2 ~ "sent" && $2 > "1488192216263" && $2 < "1488192216269"'

Comment: why `awk` or `grep`? ... to use `jq` for parser `json` ...

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. because I am working on a server and I dont want to install jq :S

Comment: why `'$2 ~ "sent"` ? I don't see this in the example input

Answer (score 2):

`awk`, `sed` or `grep` are great tools for working with text. But they are not good at working with `json`. Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to work with json documents:

```
jq -s --argjson low "1488192216263" --argjson up "1488192216269" \
    '.[]|select(.timestamp["$date"]>=$low and .timestamp["$date"]<=$up)' file.json
```

Comment: Good solution but Do you know another solution using awk or grep? Because I am working on a server and I dont have jq :(

Comment: @cdwcew Install it. Alternatively you might use Python. Any server comes with Python nowadays

Answer (score 0):

The following awk will get you:

```
awk -F '[^0-9]+' '{ if ($2 >= 1488192216263 && $2 <= 1488192216269) print $0 }' jsonfile.json
```

Comment: What is if `lower` boundary is `148819221753` and `upper` boundary is `148819231291` ? You say you suggest to rewrite the regex anytime when the boundaries change?

Comment: James, in this case you only print the timestamp, I need the entire line :)

Comment: @cdwcew, modified to print entire line

Comment: `$2 >= 1488192216263 && $2 <= 1488192216269` is enough as the body of the script.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
gawk -F'[{} ]' '($6 > 1488192216263 && $6 < 1488192216269)' timestamp
```